# VB.net Variable Scope and SQL Reader

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an object that I created that handles SQL queries. The function that actually handles the query is:

```
Function Execute_Command(ByVal strSQLCommand As String)

    Dim sqlReturnInfo As SqlDataReader
    Dim sqlQuery As New SqlCommand

    sqlQuery = sqlMainDBCon.CreateCommand()
    sqlQuery.CommandText = strSQLCommand
    sqlReturnInfo = sqlQuery.ExecuteReader

    Return sqlReturnInfo
End Function
```

When I execute the code it works fine the first time, but the 2nd time I get an error saying that sqlReturnInfo is not closed.

I fixed the problem by putting sqlReturnInfo = Nothing at the top after the declaration.

My understanding though, is that once this function finishes, the sqlReturnInfo should go out of scope and be destroyed automatically, and then once the function runs again the sqlReturnInfo is recreated as a new object, therefore sqlReturnInfo = nothing should not be nescessary/

I have seen this type of issue in one or two other areas in my code as well, out of scope variables persisting...

Am I doing something wrong, or is my understanding of variable scope incorrect?

Thanks
-RW

Comment: Not all objects follow that rule, dispose when done no matter what method you use. Using/End Using blocks are the best - it takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Garbage Collection` - not all objects follow that rule(COM objects, Streams, graphics objects, Fonts, Bitmaps(the worst), etc...), dispose when done no matter what method you use(Sub/Function). Using/End Using blocks are the best - it takes care of that for you. My rule of thumb, if you see a Dispose method on a class object - **Use It!** The reason they have them is the engineer knew it would have problems getting collected so they made a method to assist with it.

Your object has the following statement on it:

`You must explicitly call the Close method when you are through using the SqlDataReader to use the associated SqlConnection for any other purpose.`

Comment: OK I think I got it... I just declared the SqlDataReader in the object declaration and then created another function to close it. Then after it returns the sqlReturnInfo the next line runs the close_connection function. Seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the .Close() function when you are done:

```
sqlReturnInfo.Close()
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx